# SwipeRefreshLayout progress not hiding when using data binding

Tags: android, android-livedata, swiperefreshlayout

Following [How to set SwipeRefreshLayout refreshing property using android data binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40960599/how-to-set-swiperefreshlayout-refreshing-property-using-android-data-binding/40961880) I'm trying to bind `SwipeRefreshLayout` using data binding but SwipeRefreshLayout's progress is not getting hide.
Below is my code that i'm using it:

**ViewModel**

```
public class StateViewModel extends BaseViewModel {
 public MutableLiveData<Boolean> isLoading; 

 public void getItemStateDetails() {
    isLoading.setValue(true);
    scanTypePosition.setValue(0);
    getCompositeDisposable().add(
            getRepositoryManager().getItemStates()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(this::onSuccess, this::onError));
} 

private void onError(Throwable throwable) {
    isLoading.setValue(false);
    errorMsg.setValue(throwable.getMessage());
}

  private void onSuccess(List<State> states) {
        isLoading.setValue(false);
        lstState.setValue(states);
    }
}
```

**Layout**

```
     <variable
            name="stateModel"
            type="story.stateupdate.stateselection.StateViewModel" />

     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                apps:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                    android:id="@+id/pullToRefresh"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:onRefreshListener="@{() -> stateModel.getItemStateDetails()}"
                    app:refreshing="@{stateModel.isLoading}">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/stateRecyclerView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

In the above code, the variable `isLoading` is getting changed from `true` to `false` but the progress is still visible. Can anyone point out what mistake I'm doing?

Comment: @Jeel tried but getting error message Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:isRefreshing'

Comment: Why don't you pass your view object to method `getItemStateDetails()` and disable it programmatically there once your condition satisfied?

Comment: @Jeel since i heard from some developer we should avoid having reference to any kind of view in the viewmodel classes so that we cannot leak memory & make it testable.

Comment: Okay, agree with your point. One more thing is that how you're updating view from your BR class. because throughout code, there nothing that notifies about data change to your view. `i.e. notifyPropertyChanged(BR.isLoading)`

Comment: for now i'm going to do it programatically something like 
 stateFragmentBinding.pullToRefresh.setRefreshing(isLoading); later i will do research why app:refreshing="@{stateModel.isLoading}" is not working. Thanks Jeel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try to update `SwipeRefreshLayout` through the `SwipeRefreshLayout.post()` method:

```
SwipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
            SwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(isLoading);
       }
});
```

---

Or you can try to create a custom view that extend from `SwipeRefreshLayout` as below:

```
public class CustomSwipeRefreshLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout {
    public CustomSwipeRefreshLayout(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomSwipeRefreshLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void setRefreshing(final boolean refreshing) {
        post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                CustomSwipeRefreshLayout.super.setRefreshing(refreshing);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i need to do it using my xml file.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StateViewModel extends BaseViewModel implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
 SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

 public void getItemStateDetails() {
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing ( true );
    scanTypePosition.setValue(0);
    getCompositeDisposable().add(
            getRepositoryManager().getItemStates()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(this::onSuccess, this::onError));
} 

private void onError(Throwable throwable) {
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing ( false);
    errorMsg.setValue(throwable.getMessage());
}

  private void onSuccess(List<State> states) {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing ( false);
        lstState.setValue(states);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't have a reference of SwipeRefreshLayout object in my stateViewModel since there will be chances of leaking memory.